# Angular how to properly use element-resize-detector

Tags: angular, typescript, resize

I installed element-resize-detector and found following service to use it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import * as elementResizeDetectorMaker from 'element-resize-detector';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ResizeService {
   private resizeDetector: any;

  constructor() {
      this.resizeDetector = elementResizeDetectorMaker({ strategy: 'scroll' });
  }

  addResizeEventListener(element: HTMLElement, handler: Function) {
     this.resizeDetector.listenTo(element, handler);
  }

  removeResizeEventListener(element: HTMLElement) {
     this.resizeDetector.uninstall(element);
  }
}
```

Now I want to set my canvas to fullscreen:

```
@ViewChild('canvas', {static: true}) canvas: any;
private ctx: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
   
   this.resizeService.addResizeEventListener(this.canvas, (elem: 
   ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>) => {
      elem.nativeElement.width = innerWidth;
      elem.nativeElement.height = innerHeight;
      drawStuff(...);
   });
   
}
```

I get following Error:
"Invalid arguments. Must be a DOM element or a collection of DOM elements."
in the line where I add the resize-event-listner. Also I am not sure (if the other think worked) if my commands of setting the size are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I found for the problem:

```
@ViewChild('canvas', {static: false}) canvas?: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
private ctx: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {    
  if(this.canvas != null) {
     this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

  this.resizeService.addResizeEventListener(this.canvas.nativeElement, (elem: any) => {
    
    if(this.canvas != null) {
      this.canvas.nativeElement.width = innerWidth;
      this.canvas.nativeElement.height = innerHeight;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < chart.getData().length; i++) {
      if(this.canvas != null)
        drawStuff(...);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Although it isn't perfect (the aspect ratio always fits with the width and doesn't always use the full available height) it is quit solid.